# Change in Size Of PNG File after writing byte array to it

Tags: android, image, file-writing

I have created FileOutputStream object, and in that file i have written byte array of size 2515 bytes. I saved file on SD Card as PNG image. After seeing properties of that image size changes to 2389 bytes. I checked that byte array in HexEditor and created another PNG, its size is 2515 bytes it was right.
Below is my code to write byte array in PNG file.Please let me know, where i am wrong. Thanks in advance.

---

```
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(Path);
int nLen = byteArray.length;
for(int i = 0 ; i < nLen ; i++)
{
    outStream.write(byteArray[i]);
}
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

**This is other method i have tried**

```
FileOutputStream outStream1 = new FileOutputStream(m_strRgnGroupPath);
int nLen = byteArray.length;
outStream1.write(byteArray,0,nLen);
outStream1.flush();
outStream1.close();
```

Comment: You should start to show how you put a png image in that byte array. And put the values/lengths/sizes in comments at the right place in the text. So what is nLen? An outStream.close() might help.

Comment: 'checked that byte array in HexEditor and created another PNG,'. How does one check a byte array in an hex editor? How did you create that other PNG?

Comment: The size of byte array is 2515, after writing it to file i checked size of file it was 2398 bytes. Size reduced so the color of image changes

Comment: If you want help then you should answer all questions and try all the suggestions you got.

Comment: If nLen is 2515 then the file will be that too unless there is an exception.